# Read SWFObject from HTML page using Python

Tags: python, flash, web-scraping, swfobject

I have a web page that has data written into it using Java script like so-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var so = new SWFObject("x.swf", "main", "100%", "100%", "9");
        <!-- write the HTML to the page -->
        so.write("flashcontent");
</script>
```

The resulting page  [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pufst.jpg)  and I want to extract just the names of the folders.

Finally I would like to automate this process in such a way that when I provide the URL to this page, the code should automatically read the folder names within this SWF object. Is this possible?

Comment: Only if these SWFs specifically provide you with interfaces to access their data. If they are just random SWFs made by someone not affiliated with you, then no, you can not.

Comment: @Organis , Thanks for the input. I don't understand the nature of data that you mention here. I already have access to the data, it's kind of a data sharing module like sharepoint and I have my own login credentials to access it. It's just that there are hundreds of folders in there and I manually check which ones were downloaded and which ones were not. I wanted to automate this process by extracting the folder names and comparing them against the folders on my local drive. That way, i'll easily know which folders to download. I tried using a html scraper but apparently it doesn't work on SWF

Comment: Let me rephrase. SWF is a black box for the HTML page. Unless the script inside the SWF **explicitly** provides you with the methods you can call from the outside, you are not able to access the running SWF's content.